# Trailing slash url .htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i was confused about trailing slash, this is script i got from internet

```
  RewriteEngine On

      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

  Options All -indexes
```

My question:

1.what function of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

2.what function of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php`

3.what function of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$`

4.how can i write Rewrite url if the original url like:

`def.php?p=cpanel&m=add_user` ,

i want the link above rewrite like `cpanel/add_user`

thanks

Comment: Wrong direction. You have an _incoming_ SEO-format URI such as `/cpanel/add_user`, and you want to rewrite it to non-SEO dynamic format such as `/def.php?p=cpanel&m=add_user`. Right? Are cpanel and add_user the variable portions, or are either of them "fixed"? That is, do you want to rewrite to `/def.php?p=<first "dir">&m=<second "dir">`? And the trailing / on the incoming URI is optional?

Answer (score 0):

The rule need is this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^cpanel/([^/]+)/?$ def.php?p=cpanel&m=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means iif request is not for a valid file
- `$1` is backreference to captured string after `/cpanel/`
- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.
- `NC` is for ignore case
- `L` is for Last rule

Answer (score 0):

> 1.what function of %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> 2.what function of RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
>
> 3.what function of RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

You should read the rewrite guide http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

> how can i write Rewrite url if the original url like:
>
> def.php?p=cpanel&m=add_user ,
>
> i want the link above rewrite like cpanel/add_user

You can use this code in you .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cpanel/(.*)$ def.php?p=cpanel&m=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: i try it but if i access to that link , style of web is not found/work , why?

Comment: what happens if you access the css files from browser ? does it display def.php ?